# Xen Server, Ubuntu VM increased disk size, now will not boot

Tags: ubuntu, boot, xenserver

Citrix XenServer 6.2 Running Ubnutu Server 14.04

It had a 300GB disk attached, using XenCenter I increased the disk size to 500GB, planning on using gparted to resize the partition.

Now it will not boot. I don't get anything in the XenCenter Console. The XenCenter log shows "Starting VM" for a couple minutes before the timer stops, but no error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try restarting your XenCenter, then make right-click your server=>Properties=>Boot Options and make sure that "Hard Disk" is checked.

When that's done, if you're still having problems, try booting in recovery mode (hit the VM menu and Startup/Shutdown and hit "Start in recovery mode")

Answer (score 1):

Your Ubuntu 14.04 should be PVHVM mode as XenServer 6.2 does NOT have a Ubuntu 14.04 template (PV).

As @Jared already mentioned, make sure the HDD is ticked in boot order. I highly recommend using System Rescue CD to boot the VM and use the gparted GUI or whatever CLI command (e.g. `parted` can also adjust partion size, if it is LVM based, the LVM command lines should just work fine).

> NOTE: after resizing (growing) the partition, don't forget to grow the file system (for ext{3,4}, resize2fs).